# Swapping Variables in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I am a beginner, learning the basics of Kotlin. We were asked to swap the values of two variables (see the photo below). My question is, why is simply swapping the values of the variable not the expected solution as written in the image? It had to use a third variable.

[image: Kotlin practice - swapping variables]

Example:

```
Var x = 1
Var y = 2

println(x) // prints 1
println(y) // prints 2

x = 2
y = 1

println(x)
println(y)
```

Also, in the photo, was the Val tmp reassigned?

Comment: Think about what `x = y` does. It makes `x` reference the same value as `y`, yes? That means if you follow that immediately with `y = x` you've essentially done `y = y` since you've already assigned the value of `y` to `x`. The introduction of a temporary third variable is one way to prevent that scenario. And note that a `val` cannot be reassigned.

Comment: Are you asking why `x = 2 ; y = 1` is not the correct answer? It would only swap `x` and `y` for the specific case when `x` is 1 and `y` is 2, wouldn't it? It doesn't work for every possible value of `x` and `y`.

Answer (score 0):

This will swap two integer:

```
x=x+y  
y=x-y
x=x-y
```

Comment: Unless it overflows. Also, this runs more slowly and is less efficient, since it has to do three arithmetic operations, as opposed to three stores, some of which can often be elided by register-rename operations in the CPU's front-end.